# How to store navigator.geolocation as a string for variable?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, navigator

**Hi, I do not understand why storing the *navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition* result in a variable and use it to concatenate with other string doesn't work**

**If I just type in any city name for the *${locationName}* in the forWeather variable then it works fine but of course the point of this is that I want to use user's location. Please help**

**I literally just want the name of the location as a string to be store in *locationName* var**

```
const successfulLookup = position =>{
    const { lat, long } = position
    const forFetch = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${lat}+${long}&key=87c637778f19465f89895cad4bf83cfa`
    fetch(forFetch)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => res.results[0].components.village)
    .then(console.log)
}

const locationName = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successfulLookup)

const forWeather = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${locationName}&appid=cb79b904798a1f67e15e9d71fb81bc11`
```

Answer (score 0):

The *navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()* function is what we call asynchronous. This means that it doesn't actually return its result, but instead passes it to the callback function it expects as an argument.

You call a regular - synchronous - function as:

```
 var result = syncFunction(...args)
 // Do work on result here.
```

You call an asynchronous function essentially as:

```
    asyncFunction(...args, callback(result){ 
       // Do work on result here. 
    })
```

Comment: What have you tried and what's the confusion?